# Display: block showing all my <span>s inline

Tags: html, css

I am just learning CSS so this is probably something super basic that I am just messing up. I have a page with 2 header divs one main content div and a footer div. I just have an image and a couple of lines of text in the main content div and I want them to display vertically. I have the text broken up like I want with spans and have display:block in the CSS for the div. I thought this would display everything vertically but it is still displaying all in one line.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

```css
#a {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  width: 30%;
}

#b {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  width: 60%;
}

#c {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#d {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 50px;
}

#e {
  border:2px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px
}
```

Relating to this HTML

```html
<div id="c">
  <span><img src="../blog/assets/profile1.png" alt="Picture of Sid Watal"/></span>
  <span>There and Back</span>
  <span>My journey</span>
</div>
```

The image and following spans are all being displayed inline. There is currently no content in the other divs.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>`'s by default are inline.

You should be using **divs** if you want blocks. But if you want to force the span's in your html to be blocks (you shouldn't - you should change them to divs), just do this:

```
#c span { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thank you. The #c span worked perfectly but I took your advice and changed them all to divs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is remove the `<span>` tags, replacing them with `<div>` 
The span tag is becoming redundant, I never use it any more as a DIV behave much better in all situations. Span doesn't like to be stylised.

Keep your CSS the same.
Your new HTML:

```html
<div id="c">
  <div><img src="../blog/assets/profile1.png" alt="Picture of Sid Watal"/></div>
  <div>There and Back</div>
  <div>My journey</div>
</div>
```